# Verify $E(n)=\{(A,x)\mid A\in O(n)$ and $x\in \Bbb R^n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Verify that $E(n)=\{(A,x)\mid A\in O(n)$ and $x\in \Bbb R^n\}$.

Ok, What does $E(n)$ mean?? I have looked all through my text book and I have found nothing, I have also searched google for an extensive amount of time.

Can someone help me understand what it is asking?? I understand what is stated inside the brackets : $E(n)=\{(A,x)\mid A\in O(n)$ and $x\in \Bbb R^n\}$ where $A$ is Orthogonal and $x$ is in the Reals. What is $E(n)$???

Comment: With the help of @stressed-out, here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(n)$ is the group of rigid motions in the Euclidean geometry. Namely, translations, rotations and reflections and combinations of these basic geometric rigid motions. The Euclidean geometry here is thought to be the study of the group of transformations that preserve the Euclidean inner product (metric) on $\mathbb{R}^n$: $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle=x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n$

First, show that any inner product preserving linear transformation in the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space has to be an orthogonal transformation (of course, done at the origin because it's a linear transformation). Then see how every transformation in the plane can be done by first a translation to the origin, then applying a rotation/reflection and then translating back. It's a regular exercise. You need to know about semi-direct products and normal groups too, I guess. At least, in the approach I know, you need to show that $E(n)$ is the semi-direct product of translations with orthogonal transformations. Then you can show that any transformation in this group can be represented by an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix and $(n+1)$-dimensional vector of the form $(x_1,\cdots,x_n,1)$

You can learn about all of the mentioned material in the video lectures of the Abstract Algebra class taught at Harvard by Benedict Gross which is available for free [here](https://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra). You can also read more about this stuff in Michael Artin's Abstract Algebra which is the main reference book for the course.